# Storing data input by the user

Tags: java

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to store information I want to get from a user and then return those same stats at the end of the method. The problem in question is to repeatedly ask the user to name animals and how many of said animals remain in the wild. I then want my program to store these inputs without creating a few hundred variables (the problem in question) and then print the least endangered animal when the loop is terminated.

If what I'm asking is unclear, here is the fragment of code that is causing me trouble:

```
while (!animals.equalsIgnoreCase("Exterminate"))

{

   animals = input("Name an animal");

   if (animals.equalsIgnoreCase("EXTERMINATE"))

   {

    print("The least endangered animal is " + animals);

    print("There are still " + numberAnimals + " left in the wild");

    break;

   }

   else

   {

    remaining = input("How many are left in the wild?");

    numberAnimals = Integer.parseInt(remaining);

   }   

}
```

I am aware that arrays are likely to solve this problem but I don't understand how I would implement one into the while loop.

EDIT: The essence of my problem is trying to find a way to print the least endangered animal at the end of the loop because, as it stands, the terminate code 'exterminate' gets printed instead of the animal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to keep updating two variables, 1 variable for keeping the max number of animals entered by user so far, 1 variable for keeping the name of the animal with the max number:

```
    String animals = input("Name an animal");

    int numberAnimals;
    int maxNumAnimals = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // initialize as the smallest int value

    String leastEndangeredAnimal = "";
    while (!animals.equalsIgnoreCase("Exterminate")) {
            remaining = input("How many are left in the wild?");
            numberAnimals = Integer.parseInt(remaining);
            if (maxNumAnimals < numberAnimals) {
                maxNumAnimals = numberAnimals;
                leastEndangeredAnimal = animals;
            }
        animals = input("Name an animal");
    }

    print("The least endangered animal is " + leastEndangeredAnimal);

    print("There are still " + maxNumAnimals + " left in the wild");
```